MAUI DataGrid Fill (Android)
I am trying to make datagrid fill info from the sql query.
I have worked off my working WPF build and for some reason I can't get the data to fill the Table.
I have used dg:datagrid, Uranium, (DevExpress (gives loading errors)), and making my own grid.
None have given me data back.
C# code
string jobs = ("SELECT * FROM " + Table); // Selecting All Jobs ---------
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(jobs, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num0", "0");
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dat = new DataTable(Table);
    sda.Fill(dat);
    dataview.ItemsSource = dat.DefaultView;

    conn.Close();
    dat.Dispose();
    StatusArea.Text = "Loaded All Jobs";
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    StatusArea.Text = "";

}

DG XMAL
<dg:DataGrid x:Name="dataview"  SelectionMode="Single" HeaderBackground="Grey" RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="25" HeaderBordersVisible="True" Margin="0,5,0,0" >
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>

     <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Id"  Width="30">
         <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Source=Id}"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                           </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                           </dg:DataGridColumn>

                            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Business" PropertyName="CBusniess" Width="60*">
                                <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Entry Text="{Binding Source=c_location}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridColumn>

                            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Date" PropertyName="JobDate" Width="40*">
                                <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Entry Text="{Binding Source=job_date}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridColumn>

                            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Location" PropertyName="LAddress" Width="80*">
                                <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                     <Entry Text="{Binding Source=l_location}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
         </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridColumn>
</dg:DataGrid.Columns>
     <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
           <dg:PaletteCollection>
                 <Color>#ababab</Color>
                 <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
         </dg:PaletteCollection>
    </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
</dg:DataGrid>

Uranium Grid
<material:DataGrid x:Name="dataview" ItemsSource="{Binding}" UseAutoColumns="False" Background="Transparent" SelectionColor="Teal" IsVisible="Visible" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <material:DataGrid.Columns>

        <material:DataGridColumn ValueBinding="{Binding Id}" Title="Job Id" IsVisible="True" Width="Auto"/>

        <material:DataGridColumn ValueBinding="{Binding c_business}" Title="Business" IsVisible="True" Width="Auto"/>

        <material:DataGridColumn ValueBinding="{Binding job_date}" Title="Job Date" IsVisible="True" Width="Auto"/>

        <material:DataGridColumn ValueBinding="{Binding l_address}" Title="Location" IsVisible="True" Width="Auto"/>
        
    </material:DataGrid.Columns>

</material:DataGrid>

Own Grid
<CollectionView x:Name="dataview">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Job Id" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Business" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Job Date" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Location" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding c_business}" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding job_date}" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding l_address}" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}"/>
            </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>



Don’t use DataTable
